# IntelliJ - method reference may change semantics

Tags: java, intellij-idea, lambda

I have following code:

```java
return userService.getAll()
    .stream()
    .map(User::getRoleName)
    .map(roleName -> roleService.findRoleByName(roleName))
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

It seems that `roleName -> roleService.findRoleByName(roleName)` could be replaced by a method reference (namely a *Reference to an instance method of a particular object*) however IntelliJ IDEA warns that this may change semantics:

[image: screenshot]

How could it change semantics? Would it change semantics?

Comment: What does IntelliJ produce when you use that tool? "Change semantics" seems a little hard to interpret accurately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you do not follow the rules of clean functional programming, there may be a change of semantics when you convert a lambda to a method reference.

The difference is that the method reference will be resolved only once when the stream is being built. But in the lambda expression the code for getting the method can be evaluated in each execution of the lambda.

Here is a short self-contained example for demonstration:

```
public class Test40 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Function<Integer, Integer> f2 = n -> 2 * n;
    Function<Integer, Integer> f3 = n -> 3 * n;
    Function<Integer, Integer>[] funcArray = new Function[1];

    funcArray[0] = f2;
    Stream.of(1, 2, 3)
          .peek(n -> { if (n > 1) funcArray[0] = f3; })
          .map(funcArray[0]::apply)            // Method reference, '::apply' could be omitted
          .forEach(System.out::print);         // prints 246
    System.out.println();

    funcArray[0] = f2;
    Stream.of(1, 2, 3)
          .peek(n -> { if (n > 1) funcArray[0] = f3; })
          .map(n -> funcArray[0].apply(n))     // Lambda
          .forEach(System.out::print);         // prints 269
    System.out.println();
  }
}
```

How to avoid this problem: Do not use side effects when working with streams. Do not use `peek` for processing! This method exists mainly to support debugging (have a look at the javadoc).

Comment: I would also add: Do not use forEach for anything but sout or logging as it's also a side effect and is not recommended.

Comment: Yes, ```forEach``` is also there for side effects. There are better (functional) ways in most cases, therefore ```forEach``` should be avoided. My intention was not to be complete with what not to do. Just as my example uses ```peek```, I wanted to say: "Don't do this at home" :-)